# How does the Arrow function work in ECMAScript6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am working on mathematical program and ready to implement new feature of `ECMAScript6` `Arrow`.
Which is very similar to `Lambda` expression in `C#`.

```
let square = y => y * y;
console.log(square(4));
```

I achieved my goal after using `Arrow` function but still confuse how the `Arrow` function is works.

Is it work like `Lambda` expression.Can anyone guide me on that.

Thanks

Comment: "An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the `this` value. Arrow functions are always anonymous." direct from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: "How it works" in what sense? Like the underlying JS engine implementation?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Hi @FelixKling after got answer from @Moogs , i able to understand the working of `Arrow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially doing this:

```
var square = function(y) {
  return y * y;
}.bind(this);
```

where `this` is bound to the outer scope.

Comment: The note about binding can be shown by changing the closing `};` to `}.bind(this);`

Comment: I'd appreciate a reason for the downvote so that I can improve the quality of my answers.